# How do I check if a user is already logged in in the background on Azure AD

Tags: javascript, redirect, azure-active-directory, saml, saml-2.0

I am using SAML2 for authentication purposes with Azure AD.
When a user goes to my landing page, I need to check in the background if he is already logged in to the IDP (Azure AD).
Some users are employees, which have accounts in AD, some are guests, which require a different auth flow.

How do I check in the background, without redirecting the landing page to the Azure AD sign in page?

I can't use iframe to silently check this, as MS AD has `X-Frame-Options = 'DENY'.`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible using SAML SSO and Azure AD. You can specify the IsPassive flag in the SAML authn request but if the user isn't logged, instead of returning an error SAML response, Azure AD displays an error message in the browser.

However, I would have thought that you would want to distinguish between users with accounts in AD (regardless of whether they're currently logged in or not) and non-AD users. If so, the best option might simply be to prompt the user to select their identity provider (Azure AD etc).